# I can't view the different values of my Player instance during a match

Tags: java, sql

I'm sure my problem is simple, but since I'm a java beginner, I'm having a hard time solving it. I've created a program that simulates soccer matches.

Here are my 3 Classes: Championship, Match and Players.

A Championship consists of a maximum of 10 encounters, played by a maximum of 23 players.

```
public class Joueur  implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "jid", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long jid ;
    @NotNull
    @Column(columnDefinition = "ENUM('AC','SA','AID', 'AIG', 'MO', 'MLD', 'MLG', 'MR','MD','MG','MDF','DD', 'DG', 'DC','GB')")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Poste poste;
    private float minJoue;
    private int but;
    private int passe;
    private int point ;
    private double cote;
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "NOM")
    private String nom;


    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "joueurs")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Rencontre> rencontres;

  

 public class Rencontre{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "rid", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long rid;
    private String nomEquipe;
    private String nomAdversaire;
    private int butEquipe;
    private int butAdversaire;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "ENUM('DIV1', 'DIV2', 'DIV3', 'DIV4', 'DIV5')")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Division divAdversaire;
    private int pointRencontre;
    private Long idChamp;
    private String hommeDuMatch;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "rencontre_joueur",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "rid") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "jid") })
    private List<Joueur> joueurs;


    public void addJoueur(Joueur joueur) {
        this.joueurs.add(joueur);
        joueur.getRencontres().add(this);
    }

    public void removeJoueur(long jid) {
        Joueur joueur = this.joueurs.stream().filter(t -> t.getJid() == jid).findFirst().orElse(null);
        if (joueur != null) {
            this.joueurs.remove(joueur);
            joueur.getRencontres().remove(this);
        }
    }

@Entity
@Data
@Table (name="Championnat")
public class Championnat implements Serializable {


    //ATTRIBUTS
    @Id
    @Column(name = "idChamp", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idChamp;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "ENUM('DIV1', 'DIV2', 'DIV3', 'DIV4', 'DIV5')")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Division division;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "ENUM('ENCOURS', 'RELEGATION', 'MAINTIEN', 'PROMOTION')")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Statut statut;
    private int pointActuelle ;
    private int promotion;
    private int maintien;
    @Column(name = "MATCH_JOUE")
    private int nbrDeMatchJoue;
    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "idChamp" , referencedColumnName= "idChamp")
    private List<Rencontre> rencontres = new ArrayList<>(10);

}
```

I entered the player list manually into the database. http://localhost:8080/Joueur/all

```
[{"jid":1,"poste":"AC","nom":"HAALAND","minJoue":5.56,"but":10,"passe":8,"cote":3.921875,"point":0},{"jid":2,"poste":"AC","nom":"JESUS","minJoue":1.78,"but":2,"passe":3,"cote":6.5,"point":0},{"jid":3,"poste":"AC","nom":"LUKAKU","minJoue":2.0,"but":2,"passe":1,"cote":6.0,"point":0},{"jid":4,"poste":"AC","nom":"LAUTORO","minJoue":1.0,"but":1,"passe":1,"cote":6.0,"point":0},{"jid":5,"poste":"AC","nom":"MBAPPE","minJoue":0.0,"but":0,"passe":0,"cote":0.0,"point":0},{"jid":6,"poste":"AC","nom":"RONALDO","minJoue":0.0,"but":0,"passe":0,"cote":0.0,"point":0},{"jid":7,"poste":"AC","nom":"HULK","minJoue":0.0,"but":0,"passe":0,"cote":0.0,"point":0},{"jid":8,"poste":"AC","nom":"DAVID","minJoue":0.0,"but":0,"passe":0,"cote":0.0,"point":0},{"jid":9,"poste":"AC","nom":"LEWANDOWSKI","minJoue":0.0,"but":0,"passe":0,"cote":0.0,"point":0},{"jid":10,"poste":"SA","nom":"DELPIERO","minJoue":0.0,"but":0,"passe":0,"cote":0.0,"point":0},
```

What's my PROBLEM???

When these players play a match and I ask to see the stats of each player DURING THAT MATCH (for example: http://localhost:8080/Rencontre/find/1 ), which returns the details of match 1, I receive the OVERALL STATISTICS of the players and not the stats of the match.

```
{"rid":1,"nomEquipe":"Joga Bonito FC","nomAdversaire":"RENCONTRE1","butEquipe":3,"butAdversaire":1,"divAdversaire":"DIV1","pointRencontre":3,"idChamp":1,"hommeDuMatch":"HAALAND","joueurs":[{"jid":1,"poste":"AC","nom":"HAALAND","minJoue":5.56,"but":10,"passe":8,"cote":3.921875,"point":0},{"jid":2,"poste":"AC","nom":"JESUS","minJoue":1.78,"but":2,"passe":3,"cote":6.5,"point":0}]}
```

I think this error comes from the fact that I don't create a new player to play a match, but I select my instance already created in my database to play the various matches.

I did a console.log() of my match BEFORE SAVING, and I noticed that the player's stats during the match were displayed.

```
*******METHODE SCORE***********Liste des joueurs de la rencontre:**********APRES*************[Joueur{jid=1, poste=AC, minJoue=1.0, but=1, passe=1, point=0, cote=5.5, nom='HAALAND'}]
*****************UPDATE*********************[Joueur{jid=1, poste=AC, minJoue=1.0, but=1, passe=1, point=0, cote=5.5, nom='HAALAND'}]
```

But after calling the UPDATE method of my rencontreService, if I ask to see the encounter, the global values of my attributes in the database will be displayed.

rencontreService(part)

```
 @Override
    public Rencontre updateRencontre(Rencontre r) {
        score(r);
        System.out.println("*****************UPDATE*********************" + r.getJoueurs());
        return rencontreRepository.save(r);
    }



 // MODIFICATION DES POINTS ET DES MATCHS JOUEES
    public void score(Rencontre rencontre){

        Championnat champ = championnatServiceImpl.getChampionnat(rencontre.getIdChamp());
        int  NBR_DE_MATCH_MAX = 10;

        System.out.println("*******METHODE SCORE***********Liste des joueurs de la rencontre:**********AVANT*************" + rencontre.getJoueurs());
        rencontre.setButEquipe(joueurServiceImpl.totalButEquipe(rencontre.getJoueurs()));

        //VERIFICATION DU SCORE  + CHANG POINT RENCONTRE + CHANG POINT CHAMPIONNAT
        if (rencontre.getButAdversaire() < rencontre.getButEquipe()) {
            rencontre.setPointRencontre(PointMatch.WIN.getValue());
            int pointChamp = champ.getPointActuelle();
            champ.setPointActuelle(pointChamp + rencontre.getPointRencontre());
        }else if (rencontre.getButAdversaire() > rencontre.getButEquipe()){
            rencontre.setPointRencontre(PointMatch.LOST.getValue());
            int pointChamp = champ.getPointActuelle();
            champ.setPointActuelle(pointChamp + rencontre.getPointRencontre());
        }else {
            rencontre.setPointRencontre(PointMatch.EGALITY.getValue());
            int pointChamp = champ.getPointActuelle();
            champ.setPointActuelle(pointChamp + rencontre.getPointRencontre());
        }
        //INCREMENTATION DU NOMBRE DE MATCH JOUEES CHAMPIONNAT
        int nbrMatch = champ.getNbrDeMatchJoue();
        nbrMatch++;
        champ.setNbrDeMatchJoue(nbrMatch);

        //VERIFICATION DU STATUT ET FIN DE CHAMPIONNAT
        if (champ.getNbrDeMatchJoue() <= NBR_DE_MATCH_MAX &&  champ.getPointActuelle() >= champ.getPromotion()) {
            champ.setStatut(Statut.PROMOTION);
        } else if (champ.getNbrDeMatchJoue() <= NBR_DE_MATCH_MAX && champ.getPointActuelle() < champ.getPromotion() && champ.getPointActuelle() >= champ.getMaintien()) {
            champ.setStatut(Statut.MAINTIEN);
        } else if (champ.getNbrDeMatchJoue() >= NBR_DE_MATCH_MAX && champ.getPointActuelle() < champ.getMaintien()) {
            champ.setStatut(Statut.RELEGATION);
        } else {
            champ.setStatut(Statut.ENCOURS);
        }
        this.championnatServiceImpl.updateChampionnat(champ);

        joueurServiceImpl.totalButJoueur(rencontre.getJoueurs());
        joueurServiceImpl.totalPasseJoueur(rencontre.getJoueurs());
        joueurServiceImpl.totalMinuteJoueur(rencontre.getJoueurs());
        joueurServiceImpl.totalCoteJoueur(rencontre.getJoueurs());
        System.out.println("*******METHODE SCORE***********Liste des joueurs de la rencontre:**********APRES*************" + rencontre.getJoueurs());
    }
```

joueurService(part)

```
    public void totalButJoueur(List<Joueur> joueurs) {

        List<Joueur> listJoueur = new ArrayList<>();
        listJoueur = getAllJoueur();

        for (Joueur jou : listJoueur) {
            int jouBut = jou.getBut();
            for (Joueur j : joueurs) {
                int jBut = j.getBut();

                if (jou.getJid() == j.getJid()) {
                    jou.setBut(jouBut + jBut);

                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void totalPasseJoueur(List<Joueur> joueurs) {

        List<Joueur> listJoueur = new ArrayList<>();
        listJoueur = getAllJoueur();

        for (Joueur jou : listJoueur) {
            int jouPasse = jou.getPasse();
            for (Joueur j : joueurs) {
                int jPasse = j.getPasse();

                if (jou.getJid() == j.getJid()) {
                    jou.setPasse(jouPasse + jPasse);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void totalMinuteJoueur(List<Joueur> joueurs) {

        List<Joueur> listJoueur = new ArrayList<>();
        listJoueur = getAllJoueur();

        for (Joueur jou : listJoueur) {
            float jouMin = jou.getMinJoue();
            for (Joueur j : joueurs) {
                float jMin = j.getMinJoue();

                if (jou.getJid() == j.getJid()) {
                    jou.setMinJoue(jouMin + jMin);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void totalCoteJoueur(List<Joueur> joueurs) {

        List<Joueur> listJoueur = new ArrayList<>();
        listJoueur = getAllJoueur();


        for (Joueur jou : listJoueur) {
            double jouCote = jou.getCote();
            for (Joueur j : joueurs) {
                double jCote = j.getCote();
                if (jou.getJid() == j.getJid()) {
                    if (jou.getCote() == 0) {
                        jou.setCote(jCote);
                    } else {
                        double moyenneCote = (jouCote + jCote) / 2;
                        jou.setCote(moyenneCote);
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    }
```

WHAT I WANT?

I'd like to be able to keep the stats of each player during matches, so that I can make statistical calculations for each championship, such as having a table of the top scorer, passer, playing time, etc. for EACH CHAMPIONSHIP.

In short, I think that since I never instantiate my players, it's the direct attributes of the players that I manipulate, and so when I call my different encounters, it's normal that I see the data present in the database.

thank you for your help